# Typing a unexpected input causes loop to fail (C)

Tags: c, loops

While testing a program(in C) to prevent any bugs, I clicked \ by accident when the program asked for an integer. The while loop then starts failing. An example:

```
int a;
while(1){
    scanf("%d",&a);printf("%d\n",a);
    a--;
    if(a==0){break;}
}
```

Whenever I type a number, it is supposed to print the same number. But when I type a character, it will print out all numbers below the previous input and then starts printing all numbers below it till 1. 
Can anyone give a clue on fixing this problem? Thanks a lot.

Edit: This program is just a sample of the bug, the actual program is much larger than this.

Comment: I would suggest you not use scanf.  At the very least, check its return value.

Comment: What is the intent of your program? Is it to print the values below the given number until you reach 0?

Comment: @user5478656 This program just prints out what you typed until you type 0.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thanks a lot, fixed the problem

Answer (score 0):

You won't need a while loop to print just the number you entered. This would be enough :

```
int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d\n",a);
```

Or if you want to print from the input number till One :

```
int a;
while(1){
    scanf("%d",&a);
    printf("%d\n",a);
    a--;
    if(a<=0){break;}
}
```

Use `a<=0` to compare since it would not create an infinite loop even if you entered a wrong input.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you don't need a--.

```
int a;
while(1){
   scanf("%d",&a);
   printf("%d\n",a);
   if(a==0)
      break;
}
```